# Text color in the HUD

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let boxWidth: CGFloat = 96
        let boxHeight: CGFloat = 96

        let boxRect = CGRect(x: round((bounds.size.width - boxWidth) / 2),
                             y: round((bounds.size.height - boxHeight) / 2),
                             width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)

        let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: boxRect, cornerRadius: 10)
        UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 0.8).setFill()
        roundedRect.fill()

        if let image = UIImage(named: "Checkmark") {
            let imagePoint = CGPoint(
                x: center.x - round(image.size.width / 2),
                y: center.y - round(image.size.height / 2) - boxHeight / 8)
            image.draw(at: imagePoint)
        }

        let attribs = [ kCTFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 66.0), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attribs as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
        let textPoint = CGPoint(
            x: center.x - round(textSize.width / 2),
            y: center.y - round(textSize.height / 2) + boxHeight / 4)
        text.draw(at: textPoint, withAttributes: attribs as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])

    }
```

The text color in the HUD is black. Why and how can I change it to white ?

Comment: Not related, but any reason why not use directly `let attribs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 66.0), .foregroundColor: UIColor.white]` instead of CoreText constants, and then do a `as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NSAttributedString.Key` instead of `CoreText` keys try to replace this:

```
let attribs = [ kCTFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 66.0), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

with this:

```
let attribs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 66.0),
                                              .foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on this line

```
let attribs = [ kCTFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 66.0), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white.CGColor]
```

The foreground color of the text to which this attribute applies. The value associated with this attribute must be a CGColor object. Default value is black. [Refer here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/kctforegroundcolorattributename)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

let attribs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 66.0), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] as! [String : Any]